# How can I draw Indian horoscope charts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I was wondering if Indian horoscope charts can be drawn in LaTeX. Here is one example:

[image: Indian Horoscope Chart Example]

It has 12 divisions. And in each of the divisions there may be one or multiple Grahas with their corresponding positions in brackets (So, there may be some manipulation with space within a division). Names may be in English or any native Indian language.

This chart does not take account of the division in the center. The outside 12 divisions are only important. Each of the divisions are called rashi. There are 12 rashis. The numbers appearing in brackets beside each of the Grahas depicts the position of the same within the division in (degree, minute, second) format. Generally it doesn't, but it may happen that for some Grahas exact position is not available. In that case we only place the Graha in a division. And there are 9 Grahas to be placed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not very clear, what you are asking. Of course, it is possible to "draw" that with, say, TikZ. What have you tried, where are you having problems? Does the position of Grahas has any importance? This question shows no effort at all and thus could be considered as off-topic. Please add your work until know and ask specific questions. Thank you.

Comment: Why are there missing brackets for some Grahas? What are these randomly appearing numbers in the *13* divisions? Please kick everything out, which is not needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't include any specific requirements, shows no effort, and is effectively a "do-it-for-me" question.